# Local SQL Database file - Dates show in American format

Tags: sql, .net, wpf

I have a .NET WPF application that uses a local database.
I also have the Local Database runtime installed.
The Database was created through Visual Studio 2015.

My system environment for date display is DD/MM/YY. 
When I query the database and display in it a DataGrid, dates return as MM/DD/YYYY xx:xx:xx am/pm.

Is there a way to change this? I'm new to the whole SQL database thing.

Thanks.

Comment: Of what type date is being stored in DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a `StringFormat` to the binding, either directly in the XAML markup if you are defining the columns explicitly:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd\/MM\/yy}" />
...
```

...or by handling the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event if you are using auto generated columns:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Date") //<-- The name of your date column
    {
        e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = e.PropertyName, Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "dd/MM/yy" } };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a converter, something like

```
 public class DateValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var dateTime = (DateTime?)value;

            if (dateTime.HasValue)
            {
                return dateTime.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
            }

            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and on binding in `DataGrid` where you show your date call that converter.
And Xaml will look something like:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <!--Converters-->
        <converters:DateValueConverter x:Key=dateValueConverter />
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid x:Name="customDataGridName"
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name=dateSomething
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    Header=Date
                                    Binding="{Binding Date,Converter={StaticResource dateValueConverter}}" />
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```